# How to detect text below the window overlay in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I did window onverlay over another apps using dash bubble package now i want to detect the text below that overlay icon. e.g if i over to whtsapp and when i mover the overlay over any text i want to perform operation on that text like copy that text anything like that. I need guidance related that.